# How can I use a collection class as a static resource in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding, path, itemssource, staticresource

I have a simple class named `Customer` with 2 properties.
`public Name {get;set;}
public LastName {get;set}`
Then I made a collection class named `CustomerList` with only one public property named Customers

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public CustomerList()
    {
        Customers = new List<Customer>();
        Customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = "Foo", LastName = "Bar" });
        Customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = "Foo1", LastName = "Bar1" });
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this class as a static resouce in XAML.

```
  <UserControl.Resources> 
  <customers:CustomerList x:Key="CustomersKey">
  </UserControl.Resources>
```

and then use it in a ListBox

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lvTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomersKey}}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

if I set the ItemsSource in code behide, after instantiating the class, all work fine. If I try to set it from XAML and the static resource Nothing happens. not even if I use the `{Binding Path=Customer.Name}` or `{Binding Path=Name}`.

Clearly I miss something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the CustomerList isn't actually the list of items (does not implement IEnumerable), you need to specify what property inside the object you want to use as ItemsSource.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers, Source={StaticResource CustomersKey}}">
```

Comment: Oh! I was trying to use the path inside the DataTemplate... This was my mistake. Thank you for the answer.